# Can't replace dollar sign

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to write a python script that converts normal text into latex code. So I have to replace $, &, and % by \$, \&, and \% respectively. Also, I have to replace contents inside a square bracket by a blank string since the text was copied from Wikipedia. Here is my code :

```
import re
square_bracket = r"\[[^\]]*\]"


def formatting(text):
    no_brackets = re.sub(square_bracket, '', text)
    and_ = re.sub('&', '\\&', no_brackets)
    percentage_ = re.sub('%', '\\%', and_)
    dollar_ = re.sub('$', '\\$', percentage_)
    return dollar_


print(formatting("aca & akhil[3255d] 56 $ 72 %"))
```

Output is:

```
[Command: python3 -u /home/aca/Documents/python/basics/test.py]
aca \& akhil 56 $ 72 \$
[Finished in 0.131s]
```

I am ok with square bracket, & and %. But dollar sign makes the things messy as it converts normal text into mathematical argument in latex. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regular expression, `$` is an end anchor, so you need to escape it:

```
dollar_ = re.sub('\$', '\\\\$', percentage_)
#                 ^
#                here
```

If you do that, the output will be what you expect:

```
aca \& akhil 56 \\$ 72 \%
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But '\S' created ```invalid escape sequence '\$' ```. I could fix that by '\\$'.